# many dependencies in switch context in strategy design pattern

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

i used strategy design pattern and i have a problem with many dependencies while instantiating in passed cases in switch . is there any a clean solution for not passing these dependencies?

this my credit service:

```
class CreditService
{
    public function addCredit($transaction)
    {
        $creditContext = new CreditContext();
        $creditStrategy = $creditContext->setStrategy($transaction->transaction_type);
        $creditStrategy->add($transaction->id);
    }
}
```

and this is my CreditContext with many dependencies in `EmployerTransactionService` and in `TransactionService`

```
class CreditContext
{
    /**
     * @param $strategy
     * @return InvoiceStrategy|UserStrategy
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function setStrategy($strategy)
    {
        switch ($strategy) {
            case User::class:
                return new UserStrategy(
                    new EmployerTransactionService(new TransactionService(dependencies..),dependencies..);
            case Proposal::class:
            case Milestone::class:
                return new InvoiceStrategy(
                    new TransactionService(
                        new PaymentService(new PaymentRepository(), new CreditRepository(), new TransactionRepository()),
                        new TransactionRepository(),
                        new CreditRepository(),
                        new IncomeReportService(new IncomeReportRepository()),
                        new CreditService())
                );
            default:
                throw new \Exception('not found strategy');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would think that you could use Dependency Injection to handle this

Comment: @ChrisHaas is it kind of cascade dependency . could you show me the code?

Comment: As a professional programmer, when I first heard and read about DI and IoC, I didn’t get it until I started using the Symfony framework and could see it in action. The general pattern is you have something called a “container” where you register services (code that does something). When you request a service from the container, it figures out that service’s dependencies. If you don’t have a framework already, it might be overkill to add this to your code base, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [Dependency Injection Container](https://container.thephpleague.com/4.x/) which is the solution to all your problems

Your final code ultimately will be look like this

```php
class CreditContext
{
    protected $strategies = [
        User::class,
        Proposal::class,
        Milestone::class
    ];

    public function make($type)
    {
        if (in_array($type, $this->strategies, true)) {
            $container = Container::getInstance();

            return $container->get($this->strategies[$type]);
        }

        throw new RuntimeException('Strategy not found');
    }
}
```